# when i use webapck5,yarn dev meet this error : Library name must be a string or string array

Tags: javascript

Has anyone seen this problem before? Give me a hand.

Error output in text:

```
yarn run v1.17.3

$ webpack-dev-server   webpack --config ./webpack.dev.config.js --mode development
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from E:\demo\webpack-demo
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
× ｢wdm｣: Error: Library name must be a string or string array
    at AssignLibraryPlugin.parseOptions (E:\demo\webpack-demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\library\AssignLibraryPlugin.js:110:11)
    at AssignLibraryPlugin._parseOptionsCached (E:\demo\webpack-demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\library\AbstractLibraryPlugin.js:120:23)
    at compilation.hooks.finishModules.tap (E:\demo\webpack-demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\library\AbstractLibraryPlugin.js:60:27)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (E:\demo\webpack-demo\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:18:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (E:\demo\webpack-demo\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compilation.finish (E:\demo\webpack-demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1695:28)
    at process.nextTick (E:\demo\webpack-demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:976:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
```

Content of my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "exercise",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server   webpack --config ./webpack.dev.config.js --mode development"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "core-decorators": "^0.20.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
        "webpack": "^5.1.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        "module": "^1.2.5",
        "webpack-cli": "3.3.12",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
    }
}
```

This is my config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    target: 'web',
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: "var"
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    // externals: {
    //     "child_process": "require('child_process')",
    //     "fs": "require('fs')",
    //     "path": "require('path')"
    // },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        port: 9000
    }
}
```

This is my first StackOverflow question, begging everyone on my knees to take a look!

Comment: it feels like one `webpack` is too much. Can you try `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.config.js --mode development`

Answer (score 4):

Remove below line from webpack(unused statement):

```
libraryTarget: "var"
```

Seems like an open issue:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11632

Comment: your nethod worked,but i met another mistake;   Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Great, I would suggest raising a new SO question.